# How do I go from the G: to C: in command prompt for windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-prompt

I was downloading python for windows 10 command prompt and after getting it set up I booted up command prompt but now I can't access anything in the C:. Sorry if this is an obvious question I'm still pretty new to windows.

Answer (score 1):

if you type `cd /d C:\`
It should take you back to C: drive

Answer (score 0):

Just type `C:\`?

As far as I'm aware that should work. May be `CD C:\`